# How to add common line and text as second x-axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a graph. Several of my x-axis labels have a common label. So I want to add common text as label instead of several separate labels on x-axis as shown in the attached images. How can this be done?

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(conc = c(0, 10, 50, 100, "Positive Control"),
                 values = c(3, 3, 4, 5, 10),
                 name = c("TiO2 NP", "TiO2 NP", "TiO2 NP", "TiO2 NP", "Cyclophosamide"))

df$conc <- as.factor(df$conc)
labels2 <- paste0(df$conc, "\n", df$name)

df %>% 
  mutate(conc = fct_reorder(conc, values)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = conc, y=values, fill = conc))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",show.legend = FALSE, width = 0.6)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels2)+
  labs(x = "\n Dose (mg/kg BW)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a simple way. You have to play with `ggplot2` for some time to make something really custom. Here's my example:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    conc = fct_reorder(conc, values),
    labels2 = if_else(
      name == 'TiO2 NP',
      as.character(conc),
      paste0(conc, '\n', name)
    )
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=conc, y=values, fill = conc)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    width = 0.6
  ) +
  geom_rect(aes(
      xmin = .4,
      xmax = 5.6,
      ymin = -Inf,
      ymax = 0
    ),
    fill = 'white'
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
      y = -.4,
      label = labels2
    ),
    vjust = 1,
    size = 3.4,
    color = rgb(.3, .3, .3)
  ) +
  geom_line(data = tibble(
      x = c(.9, 4.1),
      y = c(-1.2, -1.2)
    ),
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = y
    ),
    color = rgb(.3, .3, .3),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_curve(data = tibble(
      x1 = c(.8, 4.1),
      x2 = c(.9, 4.2),
      y1 = c(-.8, -1.2),
      y2 = c(-1.2, -.8)
    ),
    aes(
      x = x1,
      y = y1,
      xend = x2,
      yend = y2
    ),
    color = rgb(.3, .3, .3),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
      x = 2.5,
      y = -1.7,
      label = 'TiO2 NP'
    ),
    size = 3.4,
    color = rgb(.3, .3, .3),
    check_overlap = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
      x = 3,
      y = -2.4,
      label = '\n Dose (mg/kg BW)'
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    check_overlap = TRUE
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 10, 2.5),
    limits = c(-2.5, 10)
  )
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you for taking time. However, does it not seem extremely long code to just add a line below the labels

Answer (score 1):

For a more automated approach, you can try placing the common variable in `facet_grid` with `scales = "free", space = "free"`, to simulate a 2nd x-axis line. The rest of the code below are for aesthetic tweaks:

```
df %>%
  mutate(conc = fct_reorder(conc, values)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = conc, y = values, fill = conc)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F, width = 0.6) + #geom_col() is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  facet_grid(~ fct_rev(name), 
             scales = "free", space = "free", 
             switch = "x") + #brings the facet label positions from top (default) to bottom
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.5)) + #adjusts the horizontal space at the ends of each facet
  labs(x = "\n Dose (mg/kg BW)") +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(arrow = arrow(ends = "both")), #show line (with arrow ends) to
                                                                  #indicate facet label's extent
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "cm"), #adjusts space between the facets
        strip.placement = "outside", #positions facet labels below x-axis labels
        strip.background = element_blank()) #transparent background for facet labels
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we just limit the arrow between 0 and 100 x-axis labels. And instead of arrows, let there be a line with two small vertical bars between 0 and 100.

Comment: Adding `angle = 90` inside `arrow()` would change the arrowheads into vertical bars. You can read `?arrow()` for more details on how to control the appearance.

Comment: As this is essentially a tweak on the x-axis line, it would be applied to every facet (i.e. including the cyclophosamide one), unfortunately. Converting the ggplot2 object to grob would allow you to manipulate each facet's line directly, though that gets very hack-ish very fast, & I wouldn't advise it unless you have a very strong use case.

Comment: I want that 2 in TiO2 as subscripted. How will it be done in the above code.