# How to use ggplot to create a custom figure label on barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data and code which produce a barplot.

```
#generate example data
rG_activity <- c("0.230", "0.335", NA, "0.368", "0.368", "0.327", "0.091", "-0.230")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.075, 0.335)", "(0.239, 0.631)", NA, "(0.234, 0.602)", "(0.284, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.340)", "(-0.311, 0.252)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.304", "-0.302", "-0.309", "-0.362", "-0.345", "-0.291", "-0.062", "-0.291")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.242, -0.266)", "(-0.268, -0.236)","(-0.256, -0.263)", "(-0.679, -0.244)", "(-0.260, -0.231)", "(-0.396, -0.086)", "(-0.272, 0.247)", "(-0.207, -0.074)")
rE_activity <- c("0.005","-0.024", NA, "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.054", "-0.013", "0.058")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.255, 0.266)", "(0.243, -0.291)", NA,"(-0.021, 0.333)", "(-0.298, 0.048)", "(-0.248, 0.240)", "(-0.266, 0.240)", "(-0.225, 0.241)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("0.211", "-0.006", "-0.098", "0.093", "-0.002", "0.203", "0.047", "0.205")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.046, 0.269)", "(0.257, -0.269)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.065, 0.251)", "(-0.274, 0.270)", "(-0.065, 0.272)", "(-0.212, 0.206)", "(-0.071, 0.280)")
rG_emotionality <- c("0.230", "0.335", "-0.309", "0.368", "0.368", "0.327", "0.091", "-0.230")
rG_emotionality_error_intervals <- c("(-0.075, 0.335)", "(0.239, 0.631)", "(-0.256, -0.263)", "(0.234, 0.602)", "(0.284, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.340)", "(-0.311, 0.252)")
rE_emotionality <- c("0.005","-0.024", "-0.098", "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.054", "-0.013", "0.058")
rE_emotionality_error_intervals <- c("(-0.255, 0.266)", "(0.243, -0.291)", "(-0.261, 0.064)","(-0.021, 0.333)", "(-0.298, 0.048)", "(-0.248, 0.240)", "(-0.266, 0.240)", "(-0.225, 0.241)")
age <- c("slope", "intercept", "36", "30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals, rG_emotionality, rG_emotionality_error_intervals, rE_emotionality, rE_emotionality_error_intervals)

#produce figure
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df_tidy <- melt(df , measure.vars = list(values=c("rG_activity","rG_task_persistence","rE_activity","rE_task_persistence", "rG_emotionality", "rE_emotionality"),
                              intervals=c("rG_activity_error_intervals","rG_task_persistence_error_intervals","rE_activity_error_intervals","rE_task_persistence_error_intervals", "rG_emotionality_error_intervals","rE_emotionality_error_intervals")))
df_tidy[ , values:=as.numeric(values)]
df_tidy[ , c("lci", "uci") := tstrsplit(gsub("[()]","",intervals),split=",",type.convert = TRUE)]
df_tidy[ , condition := c("rG_activity", "rG_persistence", "rE_activity", "rE_persistence", "rG_emotionality", "rE_emotionality")[variable]]
df_tidy[ , c("what","type") := tstrsplit(condition,split="_")]

ggplot(df_tidy) + 
  aes(x=age, y=values, ymin=lci, ymax=uci,fill=what) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black", width = 0.7) + 
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.7),width=0.25) + 
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=1) + 
  scale_fill_grey(
    start = 0.475 ,
    end = 0.8,
    na.value = "red",
    aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  geom_text(size=2.75,aes(label=values,y=if_else(values > 0, pmax(uci, lci) + 0.1, pmin(uci, lci) - 0.1)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(y = "Correlation") +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), legend.margin=margin(0, 0, 0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("6", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "slope", "intercept"),
                   labels = c("6"="Age 6", "12"="Age 12", "18"="Age 18", "24"="Age 24", "30"="Age 30", "36"="Age 36", "slope", "intercept")) + 
  geom_text(data = unique(df_tidy[is.na(values),],
            by = c("age", "type")), label = "N/A", y = 0, size = 2.5)
```

I would like to modify the code above to create a custom axis/label under my time points (6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36). I know this can be easily done on paint/photoshop, but it could be awesome if I could build it into my code. Would appreciate any tips or advice on how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add common line and text as second x-axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090154/how-to-add-common-line-and-text-as-second-x-axis-label)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542622/3358272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can turn clipping off in `coord_cartesian` and add a `geom_line` and `geom_text` to the bottom facet:

```r
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(age, values)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black", width = 0.7, aes(fill = what)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci, group = what),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), width = 0.25) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = values, group = what,
                y = if_else(values > 0, 
                            pmax(uci, lci) + 0.1, 
                            pmin(uci, lci) - 0.1)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), size = 2.75) +
  geom_text(data = unique(df_tidy[is.na(values),], by = c("age", "type")), 
            label = "N/A", y = 0, size = 2.5) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(age = as.character(c(6, 6, 36, 36)),
                              values = c(-1.1, -1.2, -1.2, -1.1),
                              type = "persistence"), aes(group = 1)) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(age = "18", values = -1.3, type = "persistence"),
            aes(label = "Age (months)"), hjust = 0) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", 
                   limits = c(6 * 1:6, "slope", "intercept"),
                   labels = c("6" = "Age 6", "12" = "Age 12", "18" = "Age 18", 
                              "24" = "Age 24", "30" = "Age 30",
                              "36" = "Age 36", "slope", "intercept")) + 
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.475, end = 0.8, na.value = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.8, 0.9), clip = "off") +
  labs(y = "Correlation") +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, -0.05), 
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
        strip.background = element_rect(linewidth = 0.5),
        plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 30, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Two things seem to have gotten thrown off in your solution: 1) The position of the labels now is no longer directly above the error bars. 2) Something seems to have occurred where the upper lines/box surrounding each variable name seems to gotten considerably thicker. How can I fix 1) and 2)? Thank you.

Comment: You can do 1) add `group = what` to the `aes` of  `geom_text` 2) add`strip.background = element_rect(linewidth = 0.5)`  to `theme`. See my update @ericm

Comment: Thank you @Allan Cameron. I'm not sure if this necessitates another thread entirely, but I am trying to adjust my figure legend to the right corner area of the figure. Trying to do so by specifying the coordinates with legend.position(), but the legend isn't ending up where I want it. I would like to place it in the right hand corner (like so https://i.imgur.com/wE64eKq.png). Could you help me with this?

Comment: @ericm add `legend.justification = "right"` in `theme`

Comment: That was a thought, but it ends up a little "too far right" than I would like. I'm trying to do it by specifying the coordinates to get it to where I would like in the screenshot.

Comment: @ericm then use `legend.justification = c(0.8, 0.5)`. Just adjust the 0.8 to some number between 0.5 and 1 that you like best. This is in the docs under `?theme`. Always worth having a look at that first if you get stuck.

Comment: I appreciate the response. The first thing that I did was consult the guide and play with the coordinates as you've shown above. The problem is that, to get the legend where I would like it, you would need to specify a negative value. This shouldn't be an issue, but, when I do so, the legend get cuts off from the plot entirely (and even a very slight incremental negative value still doesn't get the legend in the desired location on the screenshot).

Comment: @ericm I don't understand. Setting it to 0.9, 0.5 puts the legend in the same place that you show in the image you linked - see my update. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @ericm See my update - because clipping is off, we can have a floating legend based on panel co-ordinates.